# Androids Handler.post, what happens exactly

Tags: android, handler, runnable

since several days, I tried to figure out what exactly happens if I execute code in

```
void function(){

  //somePreExecutionCode
  new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
    @Override 
    public void run(){
       //someCode
    }
  });
}
```

It seems like it isn't blocking the UI, so buttons, which calls function() doesn't stuck in the clicked position until someCode has finished.
But if somePreExecutionCode starts a progressBar, the progressBar is shown at exactly the same moment, when someCode has finished.
I know, there are AsyncTasks for, but is there any other possibility?

And whats the difference between

```
new Handler().post
```

and

```
View.post
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting it simply, there are *Looper threads*, for example, *UI thread*. Such thread has its own [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html), which runs a message loop for the thread.

Such thread, typically, has a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), which processes its `Looper`'s messages - overriding  `public void handleMessage(Message msg)` or executing a `Runnable`, which was posted to it's looper's message queue.

When you're creating a `Handler` in the context of *UI thread* (like you did in your code), it gets associated with *UI thread's* looper, so your `\\someCode` runs on *UI thread*.

I guess, in your use case `new Handler().post(Runnable)` and `View:post(Runnable)` are mostly the same, as they both add a `Runnable` to the *UI thread* message queue.

But they are not the same.

- `View:post(Runnable)` will add a `Runnable` to the *UI thread* looper's message queue;
- `Handler:post(Runnable)` will add a `Runnable` to **its associated thread looper's** message queue

My explanation is pretty much intuitive, so correct me anyone if I am wrong.

Answer (score 9):

When an Android application is created, system creates a main thread of execution. This thread is referred to as UI thread and all UI related operations happen on this thread in order to avoid synchronization issues.

A [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) instance is created on this thread, which has a [MessageQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html) data structure. The Looper will be in an infinite loop waiting to read the [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) / [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) instances posted on the [MessageQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html). To add Message7 / [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) to the MessageQueue, [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is used.

When you create a Handler instance, it will be associated with the current thread of execution and the Looper instance created on that particular thread.

Hence when you post a message via a Handler, the Message is added to the MessageQueue, which will be read in FIFO order by Looper and will be delivered to the target.

new Handler().post() and View.post are bit different.

- When you post Messages via View.post, you are guaranteed the Message will be posted on UI thread's MessageQueue, since it internally uses Handler instance created on UI Thread.
- If you create Handler instance on UI thread and post the Message using it on any thread, Message will be posted to the UI thread's MessageQueue.
- If you create Handler instance on  a non-UI thread and post Messages using it, they will be posted on non-UI thread's MessageQueue.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Android View's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> The Runnable will be run on the user interface thread

According to [the Android Handler's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)):

> The Runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached

So, in the Handler's case, you can create it in any thread you want, it's a kind of anchor that will execute the Runnable you provide in the thread it was created in.

In the View.post, you will always execute the Runnable in the uI thread.

Comment: I would also add, that one has to associate a `Looper` with such a thread, by calling `Looper.prepare()` before creating a `Handler`, and by calling `Looper.loop()` after the handler is initialized.

Comment: I often use Handlers but I've never had to use Loopers... When do you have to use Loopers? Edit: Forget it, I've just seen your answer. Nice one. Good explaination.